# the hidden value is only passing the last value of the loop

Tags: php

I am trying to execute a update query.. first i was using a href to pass the id to the next page.it didn't work..now im using hidden field to pass the id to the next page..the problem here is that it is returning the last id that the while loop has fetched..Plz help me with it,,im a newbie and im stuck at this all day..Thanks in advance..

```
<html>
<body bgcolor="skyblue">
<form method= "post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upd.php">
    <table align="center" width="795" border="2" bgcolor="#CCC">
        <?php
            $i=0;
            $sel="select * from video";
            $sel_query=mysqli_query($con, $sel);
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sel_query)){
                $i++;
                $var_id=$row['v_id'];
                $var=$row['video'];
                ?>
                <tr align="center">  
                    <td  align="right">
                        <br>
                        <h2>Upadte Video <?php echo $i; ?> Link: </h2>
                     <input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" value="<?php echo 
                 $var_id; ?>" />
                        <button type="submit" name="btn">
                            Update
                        </button>
                        <td align="left"><br><textarea name="vids" rows="4" cols="50"><?php echo $var; ?>"</textarea></td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
        }
        ?> 
    </table>
</form>
```

udp.php

```
  <?php
  include ("includes/db.php");
if(isset($_POST['btn'])){
 $id=$_POST['hidden_id'];
 echo $id;}
```

Comment: where is hidden id field in your html

Comment: OMG sorry i forget to update the question..really sorry

Comment: its updated..plz have a look

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is running and generating following two HTML fields:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" value="<?php echo $var_id; ?>" />
<textarea name="vids" rows="4" cols="50"><?php echo $var; ?>"</textarea>
```

However, as their names are plain strings, only the last one is overriding.

You need to refer id in the loop.

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidden_id[<?php echo $var_id;?>]" value="<?php echo $var_id;?>" />
<textarea name="vids<?php echo $var_id;?>" rows="4" cols="50"><?php echo $var; ?>"</textarea>
```

And in $_POST,

Loop array for posted variables:

```
if (! empty($_POST)) {
  foreach ($_POST['hidden_id'] as $id => $val) {
    $textareaVal = $_POST['vids'][$id];
    // Apply your logic on database operations, etc...
  }
}
```

Comment: so your saying i should make an array of hidden field?? but i cant seem to understand that why it is being overridden?

Comment: and is there need to make a array of textarea also??

Comment: Answer to first: Yes, it is overriding because it has same name. In loop new element overrides old one with same name. Answer to second: yes, the logic is same.

Comment: and i've tried the code..its giving all the id's of the table......and i need only the corressponding one so i can only update that...